# Is it Acceptable to use Globals Variables for Debug code

Tags: debugging

I have a very well thought out object oriented structure to a large project that I am working on.  However, in areas of my code I would like to toggle debug sections on and off through a set of variables located in one easy to access area.  My question is whether this is a good practice or if I should implement an even more convoluted passing scheme to pass debug parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably take a good look at the System.Diagnostics.Debug class and how it is implemented using the Conditonal attribute.

Build something like that. Ease of use is nothing against the complexity of being *certain* you turned it all off.

And of course C# doesn't have glbal variables anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [debug class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.aspx) that has numerous methods to handle debugging, which are removed when built in release mode. Also [conditional methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288458%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) would probably help you as well.